# Как выровнять картинки по горизонтали не ломая логику item-ов?

Tags: html, css

Все картинки разного размера, как выровнять их все по горизонтали, чтобы текст после этого не "плавал" и сохранить логику item-ов. Образец того, что должно получится на картинке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.features {
  padding: 115px 0 100px;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

.features__inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.features__item {
  text-align: center;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

.features__title {
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova Bold';
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.features__text {
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova Regular';
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #5e6372;
  line-height: 1.6;
}
```

```html
<div class="features">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="features__inner">
      <div class="features__item">
        <img class="features__img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/25x25/33ff99/555555?text=PNG-1" alt="">
        <div class="features__title">From air</div>
        <div class="features__text">Pellentesque eget nunc sit amet urna ullamcorper fermentum et eu leo.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="features__item">
        <img class="features__img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/25x25/33ff99/555555?text=PNG-2" alt="">
        <div class="features__title">Best drones</div>
        <div class="features__text">Pellentesque eget nunc sit amet urna ullamcorper fermentum et eu leo.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="features__item">
        <img class="features__img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/25x25/33ff99/555555?text=PNG-3" alt="">
        <div class="features__title">Speed</div>
        <div class="features__text">Pellentesque eget nunc sit amet urna ullamcorper fermentum et eu leo.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="features__item">
        <img class="features__img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/25x25/33ff99/555555?text=PNG-4" alt="">
        <div class="features__title">Long range</div>
        <div class="features__text">Pellentesque eget nunc sit amet urna ullamcorper fermentum et eu leo.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.features {
  padding: 115px 0 100px;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

.features__inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.features__item {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.features__title {
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova Bold';
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.features__text {
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova Regular';
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #5e6372;
  line-height: 1.6;
}
```

```html
<div class="features">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="features__inner">
      <div class="features__item">
        <img class="features__img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/25x25/33ff99/555555?text=PNG-1" width="25" height="25" alt="">
        <div class="features__title">From air</div>
        <div class="features__text">Pellentesque eget nunc sit amet urna ullamcorper fermentum et eu leo.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="features__item">
        <img class="features__img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/25x25/33ff99/555555?text=PNG-2" width="25" height="25" alt="">
        <div class="features__title">Best drones</div>
        <div class="features__text">Pellentesque eget nunc sit amet urna ullamcorper fermentum et eu leo.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="features__item">
        <img class="features__img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/25x25/33ff99/555555?text=PNG-3" width="25" height="25" alt="">
        <div class="features__title">Speed</div>
        <div class="features__text">Pellentesque eget nunc sit amet urna ullamcorper fermentum et eu leo.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="features__item">
        <img class="features__img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/25x25/33ff99/555555?text=PNG-4" width="25" height="25" alt="">
        <div class="features__title">Long range</div>
        <div class="features__text">Pellentesque eget nunc sit amet urna ullamcorper fermentum et eu leo.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Задать картинке фиксированный размер и добавить свойство `object-fit`. Только размеры подогнать под нужные

```
.features__img{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

Comment: поддержку в IE так и не завезли https://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit

Answer (score 0):

Проще каждому блоку задать фиксированный размер, а картинки вставить как бэкграунды.

html:

```
<div class="features__img features__img__1"></div>
```

css:

```
.features__img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
}
.features__img__1 {
    background-image: url('../img/img1.png');    
}
```

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/397592)

Comment: @tCode Почему не является ответом?

Comment: @0xdb, потому что данный ответ на тот момент не был отредактирован, см. изменения

Comment: @tCode Но я то задал вопрос до изменений, ср. время изменения и комментария.